# orientdb create a index at the same time can't write

Tags: orientdb

orientdb server version 2.1.11

I have 5 nodes, had insert 3 million documents.

When I create a index, 5 nodes begin to create together. During index creation, cluster can't write. The log say "Quorum 2 not reached for request ".(I config write quorum is 2)

When I add a property to a class(slowly, because million documents), the same error occurred, the cluster can't write.

Is this right ? Is my usage is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 5 nodes you must set the quorum at 3 following this rule (n/2)+1, and your attempt to create an index fails because the nodes are in synchronizing with each others, so you can't write.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. you are right, I should config quorum 3. 
I feel confused and unexpectedly that the cluster can not write, because if it's in production evn, I can't let request wait too long.

Comment: Is there a way not lock the cluster, create index and write the same time.